# How to use sudo over SFTP with CyberDuck?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, root, ubuntu-10.04

I'm copying this question from over here: http://getsatisfaction.com/cyberduck/topics/can_i_use_sudo_over_sftp_with_cyberduck

I am having the same issue and finding it hard to find an answer:

> I am using Cyberduck over SFTP. I can
>   connect and browse files fine, but
>   when I try to upload, I get a
>   permissions error. Web host says I
>   need to use the 'sudo' command. I know
>   how to do this via Terminal, but it is
>   possible to to tell Cyberduck to use
>   sudo?

Please don't tell me to use root because:

> What if you don't have root access or
>   don't want to enable root access?

Comment: I'd bet you still haven't found a solution for this and actually did something similar to what jeffp suggested. But I'd love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 13):

I upload the file with cyberduck to a folder where i can write to (e.g. the home folder of the cyberduck connected user). Then i login to the machine via ssh and sudo mv the file to the desired destination folder.

Answer (score 12):

I had this same problem for a really long time, and I had resigned to simply using putty to edit files, or moving them from my home directory.

Unfortunately this is only a partial answer, as it does not work natively in linux. You might be able to use it in wine though.
Turns out it is possible to do this using winscp.

Setup a new SFTP session in winscp, 
[image: Setup page 1]

After that, go to the SFTP section of the setup, select a custom SFTP server, and type in the path to the remote sftp-server binary with sudo -s appended before it. For this to work you need to enable running sudo without a password. You can use the whereis command on the remote server to find the path to sftp-server.

[image: How to retrieve sftp-server path]

[image: Last Step]

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution is to use your sudo in ssh to modify permissions.  You could even write a small shell script to give you access while you are working and set the permissions back when you are done.

I am actually curious if there is a better way to do this, but I am pretty sure that there is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server, you might be able to claim ownership for the directory with your ssh user. After that you should be able to copy and edit data without using `sudo`.

```bash
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /your/current/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to start the remote SFTP server with sudo but I doubt you could find any SFTP GUI client supporting that.