# How to SSH in EC2 as root with cyberduck?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with some php scripts running on Amazon. The folder with the files has permission 755 (chmod 755 folder).

Everytime I login I have to change the folder permissions to change anything to files.

Question: Is it possible to login as root with cyberduck?

Note: I found this link [How to use sudo over SFTP with CyberDuck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381498/how-to-use-sudo-over-sftp-with-cyberduck) , but it is from 2010 and I don't know if that info is accurate or not.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a folder that your user should be able to read and write. Give your user account permissions to it...

1) Create a group

```
sudo groupadd mygroup
```

2) Add your user account to that group

```
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup myuser
```

3) Change the permissions of the folder such that group has execute/modify

```
sudo chown -R current_owner:mygroup myfolder
sudo chmod 776 myfolder
```

It is odd you have to change permissions every time. If this folder is deleted and re-created by another process or user, you will need to set the environment variable **umask** to 776 before creating the files and folders in your script.